# Would it be on topic to compile different information from other sites on to this site?

Tags: discussion

For example, recently I've been having a trouble of trouble finding out the difference between meaning of different pre-fixed form of rechnen. I found the answer I Was looking for but it was scattered across many sites. Would it be ontopic to compile all these information and post as self answer question on this site? (Ofc with proper linking to sources)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand what you want to do. To me it sounds as it would be off-topic, as it falls under the "can be answered by a dictionary" category. If you plan to provide more information than just the translations of the verbs, that might be different.

Comment: Here are the sites which I thought of compiling the answer from [1](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-errechnen--berechnen-und-rechnen),[2](https://www.italki.com/post/question-227911). There is difference between abrechen and rechnen already on SE. The main point of interest is the usage.

Answer (score 1):

1. The suggested approach is possibly subject to copyright issues, see [SE terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#copyright) for an idea of what has to be considered.
2. Duplicating dictionary functionality here is impossible, and for *abrechnen* as example the [definition in DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/abrechnen) seems to provide a pretty complete picture.